# Is the use of return in Ruby not idiomatic?

Tags: ruby, idioms

I have been refactoring some code today and have made a lot of my methods much neater with fairly heavy use of `return`. One thing that occurred to me is how infrequently I have seen return used in sample code, blog posts, etc, which led me to think that I'm doing something wrong.

Is using return not idiomatic in Ruby? Should I be aiming to just have my methods just return a final value through `if`/`else`, `case`/`when` statements, rather than interrupt them early with `return`?

Comment: I see them fairly commonly.  It is certainly used, although using it several times in a single method may be a sign that you need to refactor further.

Comment: Yeah, definitely going to generate a lot of opinion. I'm glad to see you do write methods like you described, that's more or less exactly what I've been doing.

Comment: https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide talks about return.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The core in Ruby is to only use return *when you need to*. If early termination with return makes your method clearer, do it. In other words:

**DO:**

```
def method(arg)
  if(arg == 0) #Special case
    return 42
  end
  arg + 46
end
```

**DON'T:**

```
def method(arg)
  return arg + 46
end
```

**BEST:**

```
def method(arg)
  if(arg == 0)
    42
  else
    arg + 46
  end
end
```

However, return is only discouraged only *when unnecessary*.